# How to add child elements dynamically to SOAP request in SOAPUI using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a request which accepts 1..n items to add to basket. default request has one "item" element with some child elements, i want to add N no of items with child element i'm able to add Item parent element using creaeElementNS now i want to add child elements to "item" like following, can someone shed some light on this

```xml
<basket:item>
<basket:itemId>222</basket:itemId>
<basket:itemCode>DEF</basket:itemCode>
<basket:item>
```

*Groovy script*

```js
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "createBasket#Request" )
def parentnode = holder.getDomNode( "//basket:createBasketRequest" )
def basketTotal=   holder.getDomNode( "//basket:itemsTotal" ) 
def itemsTag = requestDoc.createElementNS(parentnode.getNamespaceURI(), "item")
parentnode.insertBefore(itemsTag  , basketTotal)
holder.updateProperty()
```

*Current Output*

```xml
<basket:createBasketRequest>
<basket:item>
    <basket:itemId>111</basket:itemId>
    <basket:itemCode>ABC</basket:itemCode>
</basket:item>
<basket:item>
</basket:item>
    <basket:itemsTotal>500.00</basket:itemsTotal>
</basket:createBasketRequest>
```

*Desired Output*

```xml
<basket:createBasketRequest>
    <basket:item>
        <basket:itemId>111</basket:itemId>
        <basket:itemCode>ABC</basket:itemCode>
    </basket:item>
    <basket:item>
        <basket:itemId>222</basket:itemId>
        <basket:itemCode>DEF</basket:itemCode>
    <basket:item>
    <basket:itemsTotal>500.00</basket:itemsTotal>
</basket:createBasketRequest>
```

EDIT: I'm using soapUI and TestCase option, there is a GroovyScript step before add basket request step, groovy script prepares add basket request before actually sending request, for example if my testcase mentions 1 item it should request with default one item so i have no worries to add another Item elements but when my testcase says 2 items i have to create second Items elements(along with child elements) and prepare the add basket request using groovy script step before actually sending add basket request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it will work (I don't use SoapUI), but does this help?

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder      = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "createBasket#Request" )
def parentnode  = holder.getDomNode( "//basket:createBasketRequest" )
def basketTotal = holder.getDomNode( "//basket:itemsTotal" ) 

def nodeText    = '''<basket:item>
                    |    <basket:itemId>222</basket:itemId>
                    |    <basket:itemCode>DEF</basket:itemCode>
                    |</basket:item>'''.stripMargin()

def nodeHolder  = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( nodeText )
def nodeItem    = nodeHolder.getDomNode( "//basket:item" )
def importNode  = requestDoc.importNode( nodeItem, true )

parentnode.insertBefore( importNode, basketTotal )

holder.updateProperty()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, had a quick look  got (anyway i will try some more options)  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj.insertBefore() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.Node, org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj)

Comment: @StaleElementException Right, found [another page showing a possible solution](http://techdiary.bitourea.com/2013/06/soapui-inserting-external-xml-node.html), and updated my answer...  Fingers crossed ;-)

Comment: almost working just facing problem with namespaces, i'm trying to resolve them, thanks for the help

Comment: I ended up like this as i have different namespaces in requestdef itemsTag = requestDoc.createElementNS(parentnode.getNamespaceURI(), "item")

def itemIdNode = requestDoc.createElementNS(parentnode2.getNamespaceURI(),"itemId")
itemIdNode.store_text("222")
itemsTag.appendChild(itemIdNode)

def itemCodeNode = requestDoc.createElementNS(parentnode2.getNamespaceURI(),"itemCode")
itemCodeNode.store_text("DEF")
itemsTag.appendChild(itemCodeNode)

parentnode.insertBefore(itemsTag,basketTotal)
holder.updateProperty()

Comment: WHat is the type of requestDoc here?

Comment: This didn't work for me, I kept getting "Use of undefined namespace prefix: basket".

Answer (score 0):

Check out Scott Davis's post on [creating XML with groovy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg05199/)

I used MarkupBuilder to create an XML that looks exactly like what you want.

```
def sw = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)
xml."basket:createBasketRequest"(){
    "basket:item"(){
        "basket.itemId"("111")
        "basket:itemCode"("ABC")
        }
    "basket:item"(){
        "basket.itemId"("222")
        "basket:itemCode"("DEF")
        }
    "basket:itemsTotal"("500.00")
}

log.info sw
```

Output i got:

```
<basket:createBasketRequest>
  <basket:item>
    <basket.itemId>111</basket.itemId>
    <basket:itemCode>ABC</basket:itemCode>
  </basket:item>
  <basket:item>
    <basket.itemId>222</basket.itemId>
    <basket:itemCode>DEF</basket:itemCode>
  </basket:item>
  <basket:itemsTotal>500.00</basket:itemsTotal>
</basket:createBasketRequest>
```

Updating response as some part of the XML already exists and nodes just have to be appended to the root.

Try this code...

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(orgXML)
root.appendNode {
    "basket:item"{
        "basket:itemID"("222")
        "basket:itemCode"("DEF")
    }

}

log.info groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( root )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have edited my question hope that understands my requirement, Im not preparing whole XML request i just want to insert in existing request

Comment: What does your original XML look like?